# Python - get first a tag parsing HTML

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using python and beautiful soup to parse this web page. https://rpi.sodexomyway.com/dining-choices/res/sage.html In the "on the menu" section I want to get the url of the first link.

Here is the code I am using:

```
monthly_urls = soup.findAll('div',{'id':'accordion_23473'})[0]('a',href=True)
```

right now it is getting the second a tag, and I'm not sure why, I would think it would at least get both but its only getting the second one.

I would wither like to change the code so it gets the first tag or so that I could search by what the a tag says and get that.

For the second part I was just talking about for example if the a tag was

```
<a new tag </a>
```

I would want to search for "new tag"

EDIT:

full code, I need the current weeks link so either get the first one from the on the menu section to search by the date for that link...

```
    #  Created by Spencer Fontein on 5/28/14.
#  Copyright (c) 2014 Spencer Fontein. All rights reserved.

# coding: utf-8

import pprint
from lxml import etree
import cgi
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import urllib2
import cookielib
import re

#where to send the file at the end
output_path = ""#"/home/spencerf/public_html/rpi/"

def Get_website_text(url):

    # url for website        
    base_url = url

    # file for storing cookies       
    cookie_file = 'mfp.cookies'

    # set up a cookie jar to store cookies
    cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(cookie_file)

    # set up opener to handle cookies, redirects etc
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(
         urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler(),
         urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0),
         urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=0),            
         urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)
    )

    # pretend we're a web browser and not a python script
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent',
        ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) '
         'AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
         'Chrome/13.0.782.13 Safari/535.1'))
    ]

    # open the front page of the website to set
    # and save initial cookies
    response = opener.open(base_url)
    web_text = response.read()
    response.close()

    return web_text

#get union menus
def getUnionMenuUrls(soup):
    monthly_urls = soup.findAll('div',{'id':'accordion_23473'})[0]('a',href=True)
    #print soup.findAll('div',{'id':'accordion_23473'})[0]('a',href=True)
    #print soup.find(text=re.compile('9/22/2014 - 9/28/2014'))
    menu_urls = []
    url = "https://rpi.sodexomyway.com"
    for tag in monthly_urls:
        if ".htm" in tag['href']:
            name = str(tag.text)
            name = name.replace("Click ",'').replace('For ','').replace('Menu ','').replace('of ','').replace('Week ','').replace('Here ','').replace('Of ','')
            name = name.replace('January ','').replace('February ','').replace('March ','').replace('April ','').replace('May ','')
            name = name.replace('June ','').replace('July ','').replace('August ','').replace('September ','')
            name = name.replace('October ','').replace('November ','').replace('December ','')
            name = name.replace('1','').replace("2", '').replace("3", '').replace("4", '')
            name = name.replace('5','').replace("6", '').replace("7", '').replace("8", '')
            name = name.replace('9','').replace("0", '').replace('-','')
            name = name.replace('\n','rpi_russell_sage_menu').replace('/','')
            name = name.replace('!','').replace(', ','').replace(' ','').replace('College','')
            newurl = url + tag['href']
            menu_urls.append([name,newurl])
    return menu_urls


def get_xml(url):
    tag_stack = []
    output_lines = []

    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().replace('&nbsp;',"")
    xml = etree.HTML(html)

    open_tag(tag_stack, output_lines, "menu", "")
    days = xml.xpath('//td[@class="dayouter"]')
    # make the xml for each day
    for day in days:
        day_name = day.xpath('./a/@name')[0]
        safe_open_tag(tag_stack, output_lines, "day", "menu", day_name)

        dayinner_trs = day.xpath('.//table[@class="dayinner"]//tr') 
        for dayinner_tr in dayinner_trs:
            # change meal
            if (dayinner_tr.xpath('./td[@class="mealname"]')):
                meal_name = dayinner_tr.xpath('./td[@class="mealname"]/text()')[0]
                safe_open_tag(tag_stack, output_lines, "meal", "day", meal_name)

            # change counter
            if (dayinner_tr.xpath('./td[@class="station"]/text()')):                
                counter_name = dayinner_tr.xpath('./td[@class="station"]/text()')[0]
                safe_open_tag(tag_stack, output_lines, "counter", "meal", counter_name)

            # change dish
            if (dayinner_tr.xpath('./td[@class="menuitem"]')):
                item_name = "".join(dayinner_tr.xpath('./td[@class="menuitem"]/div//text()')).strip()
                safe_open_tag(tag_stack, output_lines, "dish", "counter", "")
                output_lines.append("<name>%s</name>" % cgi.escape(item_name))

    close_tags(tag_stack, output_lines, "")
    output_string = '\n'.join([line.encode('utf-8') for line in output_lines])

    return output_string

# close the tags up to the parent of last tag in tag_stack
def close_tags(tag_stack, output_lines, parent_tag):
    while tag_stack and tag_stack[-1] != parent_tag:
        top = tag_stack.pop()
        output_lines.append(' ' * len(tag_stack) + '</%s>' % top)

# open the new_tag using the suitable style based on name_property
def open_tag(tag_stack, output_lines, new_tag, name_property):
    if name_property:
        output_lines.append(' ' * len(tag_stack) + '<%s name="%s">' % (new_tag, name_property))
    else:
        output_lines.append(' ' * len(tag_stack) + '<%s>' % new_tag)
    tag_stack.append(new_tag)

# check if the new_tag parent is in the stack, if not it'll add the parent
def safe_open_tag(tag_stack, output_lines, new_tag, parent_tag, name_property):
    if parent_tag not in tag_stack:
        output_lines.append(' ' * len(tag_stack) + '<%s>' % parent_tag)
        tag_stack.append(parent_tag)
    else:   
        close_tags(tag_stack, output_lines, parent_tag)
    open_tag(tag_stack, output_lines, new_tag, name_property)

# sample use of get_xml function


# In[17]:

if __name__ == "__main__":
    base_url_u = "https://rpi.sodexomyway.com/dining-choices/res/sage.html"
    htmltext_u = Get_website_text(base_url_u)
    soup_u = BeautifulSoup(htmltext_u)
    menu_url_list = getUnionMenuUrls(soup_u)
    for menu in menu_url_list:
        if '.htm' in menu[1]:
            ofname = str(menu[0].replace(" ","A")) + ".xml"
            output_file = output_path + ofname
            open(output_file, "w").write(get_xml(menu[1]))
        else:
            print menu[0],":",menu[1], "is not valid html."
```

EDIT 2:

```
date function

def getCurrentWeekMenu(date1,date2):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    monthstr = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December"   
    months = monthstr.split(',')
    d = dict(zip(months,range(1,13))) 
    menu_1_month = d[str(date1[0])]
    menu_2_month = d[str(date2[0])]
    menu_1_day = str(date1[1][:-2])
    menu_2_day = str(date2[1][:-2])
    if menu_1_day > menu_2_day:
        if now.day >= menu_1_day:
            menu = 1
        else:
            menu = 2
    else:
        if now.day >= menu_2_day:
            menu = 2
        elif now.month > menu_1_month:
            menu = 2
        else:
            menu = 1
    return menu-1
```

Comment: Can you please give sample output which you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problems running your code

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
response = requests.get('https://rpi.sodexomyway.com/dining-choices/res/sage.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
#output of your code
print soup.findAll('div',{'id':'accordion_23473'})[0]('a',href=True)

>>> [<a href="#">On the Menu</a>,
     <a href="/images/WeeklyMenuRSDH%209-22-14_tcm1068-29436.htm" target="_blank">
                     9/22/2014 - 9/28/2014</a>,
     <a href="/images/WeeklyMenuRSDH%209-29-14_tcm1068-29441.htm" target="_blank">
                     9/29/2014 - 10/5/2014</a>,
     <a href="#">Hours of Operation</a>]

# now get the href
url = dict(soup.findAll('div',{'id':'accordion_23473'})[0]('a',href=True)[1].attrs)['href']
# output
u'/images/WeeklyMenuRSDH%209-22-14_tcm1068-29436.htm'
```

answer on second part of question

```
import re
soup.find(text=re.compile('new tag'))
```

UPDATE - adding current week filter

```
def getUnionMenuUrls(soup):                                                      
    monthly_urls = soup.findAll('div',{'id':'accordion_23473'})[0]('a',href=True)[1:3] # cut extra links
    today = datetime.datetime.today() # get todays date                          
    url = "https://rpi.sodexomyway.com"                                          
    for tag in monthly_urls:                                                      
        if ".htm" in tag['href']:                                                
            name = str(tag.text)                                                 
            datestrings = name.split(' - ') # split string and get the list of dates
            date_range = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y') for d in datestrings] # convert datestrings to datetime objects
            if date_range[0] <= today <= date_range[1]: # check if today in that range
                return url + tag['href']
```

Comment: your right that must not be the part of the code that is the problem let me post my full script, I either want to get the first link as my output, or if I can just search for the first a tag by the current week so it only get that one. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think that it is good idea to search by name, because It is always good to bind to page schema, but not to content.
If You need to get first link in menu_urls with minimum pain - use `monthly_urls = soup.findAll('div',{'id':'accordion_23473'})[0]('a',href=True)[1:2] # line 54`

Comment: okay so that works to get the first one, but I want to get the current week one, how would I go about doing that  I have added a function to main question that I made that gets the date, and then I want to get the link that is for this week, any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: you could ignore the function I posted, Im more just asking as basically as I can put it if there is a way to get the link of the current week? make sense?

Comment: I've updated my answer according to Your requirements
please note, that it returns just new url, not [name, url]

Comment: okay but i am getting an error in this line `date_range = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y') for d in datestrings]`, It also says value error: time data ' does not match format

Comment: when I add `name = name.replace('\n','').replace("'",'').replace(' ','')` I get an error: `ValueError: unconverted data remains: -9/28/2014`

Comment: when You call `.replace(' ','')` - `split(' - ')` doesn't work correctly, because You replaced spaces to nothing. You have 2 ways to solve the problem - to use `split('-')` or to calculate link with my code before calculating the name. Did it help?

Comment: I think so is there a way I can change what python thinks the date is so I can test it out more?

Comment: actually - `datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y')` is the place where You specify how string is parsed to object

Comment: not sure what you mean by that could you elaborate... and is it possible to set the date somewhere else?

Comment: I don't understand the question - please provide more info - I will give You as much info as I can